# How to build my own wireless attached storage?

Tags: bonjour, upnp, nas

Quite open question.

I wonder how can I make my own network storage such as Apple Time Capsule by using open source. I try to peek and poke around Bonjour, PnP-X, AFP and SMB ...

Is there any one already have experience to build(or write) network storage device such as Time Capsule? Could you please let me know detail step to research on this topic?

Thanks in advance,
Wonil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some web surfing, I found the below open source S/W can help me.

1) Netatalk - to support AFP on Linux

2) Avahi - to support Bonjour on Linux